# Connecting OpenCV with netbeans 7.3.1

Tags: c++, opencv, netbeans

I'm trying to use OpenCV with Netbeans 7.3.1. I have tried following the various tutorials and blogs but cannot run any of the files. The following code was listed as good example code to check the opencv installation:

```
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;
#include "opencv.hpp"
#include "opencv_modules.hpp"
int main ( int argc, char **argv ) { 
    cvNamedWindow( "My Window", 1 ); 
    IplImage *img = cvCreateImage( cvSize( 640, 480 ), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1 ); 
    CvFont font; 
    double hScale = 1.0; 
    double vScale = 1.0; 
    int lineWidth = 1; 
    cvInitFont( &font, CV_FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX | CV_FONT_ITALIC, hScale, vScale, 0, lineWidth ); 
    cvPutText( img, "Hello World!, I can now code openCV ", cvPoint( 0, 200 ), &font, Scalar    
    (255, 255, 0 ) ); 
    cvPutText( img, "in a kickass IDE ", cvPoint( 150, 300 ), &font, cvScalar( 255, 255, 0 ) ); 
    cvShowImage( "My Window", img ); 
    cvWaitKey(); 
return 0; 
}
```

The code results in the following error:
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory `/cygdrive/c/Users/Daniel/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_4'
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/Cygwin_1-Windows/cppapplication_4.exe
make[2]: Entering directory`/cygdrive/c/Users/Daniel/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_4'
mkdir -p build/Debug/Cygwin_1-Windows
rm -f build/Debug/Cygwin_1-Windows/main.o.d
g++    -c -g -I../../../../../Program\ Files/OpenCV/build/include/opencv2 -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/Cygwin_1-Windows/main.o.d -o build/Debug/Cygwin_1-Windows/main.o main.cpp
In file included from main.cpp:11:
../../../../../Program Files/OpenCV/build/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp:46:33: opencv2/core/core_c.h: No such file or directory
../../../../../Program Files/OpenCV/build/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp:47:33: opencv2/core/core.hpp: No such file or directory
../../../../../Program Files/OpenCV/build/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp:48:39: opencv2/flann/miniflann.hpp: No such file or directory
../../../../../Program Files/OpenCV/build/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp:49:39: opencv2/imgproc/imgproc_c.h: No such file or directory
../../../../../Program Files/OpenCV/build/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp:50:39: opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp: No such file or directory
../../../../../Program Files/OpenCV/build/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp:51:35: opencv2/photo/photo.hpp: No such file or directory
../../../../../Program Files/OpenCV/build/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp:52:35: opencv2/video/video.hpp: No such file or directory
../../../../../Program Files/OpenCV/build/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp:53:45: opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp: No such file or directory
../../../../../Program Files/OpenCV/build/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp:54:43: opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp: No such file or directory
../../../../../Program Files/OpenCV/build/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp:55:39: opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp: No such file or directory
../../../../../Program Files/OpenCV/build/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp:56:29: opencv2/ml/ml.hpp: No such file or directory
../../../../../Program Files/OpenCV/build/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp:57:39: opencv2/highgui/highgui_c.h: No such file or directory
../../../../../Program Files/OpenCV/build/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp:58:39: opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp: No such file or directory
../../../../../Program Files/OpenCV/build/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp:59:39: opencv2/contrib/contrib.hpp: No such file or directory
main.cpp: In function `int main(int, char**)':
main.cpp:14: error:`cvNamedWindow' undeclared (first use this function)
main.cpp:14: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in.)
main.cpp:15: error: `IplImage' undeclared (first use this function)
main.cpp:15: error:`img' undeclared (first use this function)
main.cpp:15: error: `cvSize' undeclared (first use this function)
main.cpp:15: error:`IPL_DEPTH_8U' undeclared (first use this function)
main.cpp:15: error: `cvCreateImage' undeclared (first use this function)
main.cpp:16: error:`CvFont' undeclared (first use this function)
main.cpp:16: error: expected `;' before "font"
main.cpp:17: error:`font' undeclared (first use this function)
main.cpp:17: error: `CV_FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX' undeclared (first use this function)
main.cpp:17: error:`CV_FONT_ITALIC' undeclared (first use this function)
main.cpp:17: error: `cvInitFont' undeclared (first use this function)
main.cpp:18: error:`cvPoint' undeclared (first use this function)
main.cpp:18: error: `cvScalar' undeclared (first use this function)
main.cpp:18: error:`cvPutText' undeclared (first use this function)
main.cpp:20: error: `cvShowImage' undeclared (first use this function)
main.cpp:21: error:`cvWaitKey' undeclared (first use this function)
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:86: recipe for target `build/Debug/Cygwin_1-Windows/main.o' failed
make[2]: *** [build/Debug/Cygwin_1-Windows/main.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory`/cygdrive/c/Users/Daniel/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_4'
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:59: recipe for target `.build-conf' failed
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory`/cygdrive/c/Users/Daniel/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_4'
nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:39: recipe for target `.build-impl' failed
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 2s)

Could anyone help with providing a clear set of instructions or at least pointing to a concise guide?

Thanks,
Daniel

Comment: The "No such file or directory" messages are a clue. Have you checked your include path?

Comment: I'm not sure which include path I should use there are several paths: C:\Program Files\OpenCV\include which holds two folders one called openCV and one called openCV2.

Comment: Another is C:\Program Files\OpenCV\build\include which again contains two folders with the same names. I saw a tutorial that stated that the linker should point to C:\Program Files\OpenCV\build\x64\vc10\include\opencv although I'm not sure why this is. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your include path contains `C:\Program Files\OpenCV\include`, and that the include files really are located there, replace

```
#include "opencv.hpp"
```

with

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
```

You can probably do without `#include "opencv_modules.hpp"`, otherwise it should be `#include "opencv2/opencv_modules.hpp"`